# Restrict Input type week to current week

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-livewire

I currently am creating a web app where a user picks a certain week for the data they want to view. I want to restrict the week so that the max value they can pick is the current week. Here is the code HTML I'm currently using:

```
<input type='week' wire:model='weekNotFormatted'>
```

How can I achieve this using javascript or php? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max` with date format `Y-W`:

```
<input type='week' wire:model='weekNotFormatted' max='{{ (new Carbon\Carbon)->format('Y-\WW') }}'>
```